# React-native audio player

Tags: android, react-native

How to play two audio files simultaneously in react native android app? Am using react-native-audioplayer package and if i try to play two audios

```
componentWillMount() {
    AudioPlayer.play('audio1.mp3');
    AudioPlayer.play('audio.mp3');
    }
```

the second audio is only getting played and first audio was not.
How to make both the audios to play together simultaneously?

Comment: react-native-sound module is not working with latest react-native version like 0.62.2    
                                                                                                                                         Please refer this stackoverflow question. It works for me!
                                                                 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61708473/how-to-run-multiple-tracks-at-a-time-simultaneously-in-react-native

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using `react-native-sound` instead - this definitely supports multiple audios playing at once. We've used it in multiple projects.

https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code will help you a bit, but *have not tested it*... :

```
mp1=new MediaPlayer();
mp1.setDataSource("/sdcard/" + path);
mp1.prepare();
mp1.start();
mp1.setDataSource("/sdcard/" + path);
mp1.prepare();
mp1.start();
```

Check also out this code, he has **your solution as his Problem** ;)

[music player play 2 song at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102902/music-player-play-2-song-at-the-same-time)

Comment: i think you are saying for android but i am asking for react native. And i want to store the audio file in my project directory so that i can bundle it together while building apk. And if i add it from the sdcard then how can i make use of it in my app installed in other mobile?