# How to run multiple tracks at a time / simultaneously in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**Describe the bug:**

I'm using react-native in my application, I want to play the multiple tracks at a time. I tried some node modules but they only allows me to play a song at a time.
Is there any way to do this?

**Expected behavior:**
Play the multiple songs at a time

**Platform:** 
Android

Comment: What do you use now that `react-native-audio-toolkit` is deprecated? I've tried some other packages but they don't seem to be able to do simultaneous song play

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be possible with [react-native-audio-toolkit](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-audio-toolkit) module. You could create multiple Player instance at same time and play multiple tracks.

```
import {Player} from '@react-native-community/audio-toolkit';

const PLAYER_ONE = new Player(songUrl1).play();
const PLAYER_TWO = new Player(songUrl2).play();
```

Comment: Thanks EL173. This react-native-audio-toolkit module works for me! Just one observations, for this module minSdkVersion should be 19.

Comment: Glad to help you @AbhijeetGiram

Comment: What do you guys use now that `react-native-audio-toolkit` is deprecated?

Comment: @Ryker use ```@react-native-community/audio-toolkit``` https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/audio-toolkit  instead of ```react-native-audio-toolkit```

Comment: @EL173 That's the one I looked at but it looks like there hasn't been an update in about two years? I used the package anyway but the .stop function doesn't seem to work at all
`const player = new Player(.audioUrl);

if (isPlaying) {
    player.stop();
} else {
    player.play();
}`